# Connecting to Postgres with pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, macos

**OS**: macOS High Sierra 
 
**Version**: 10.13.6 (17G6030)

I'm reading Practical SQL and I'm attempting to set up my environment, but I'm running into the following issue.

- I installed Postgres
- Ran sudo mkdir -p /etc/paths.d &&
  echo /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin | sudo tee /etc/paths.d/postgresapp
- Installed pgAdmin locally
- When I open pgAdmin there are no servers listed even though I have 3 servers listed in postgres.
- When I go to connect a server, I typed in the server name and the path. But when I type in the path I get the following error:

```
Unable to connect to server: could not connect to server: Not a directory
Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket /Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/12/bin/psql/.s.PGSQL.5432?
```

Comment: you need to add the server's to PgAdmin, please add a screenshot of what you typed in pgAdmin

Comment: Okay I figured it out using this video. 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lG2Nes-wi54

Answer (score 1):

I used the [following video to learn](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lG2Nes-wi54) how to create and connect a database from postgres to pgAdmin